# GradientColor of Drawable not changing at startup

Tags: android, gradient

i want to add a drawable with a gradient to my Header:

```
int h = header_relativeLayout.getHeight();
ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, h, getResources().getColor(R.color.SmokeyWhite),
                                       getResources().getColor(searchbarColorID),
                                       Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
mDrawable.getPaint().setShader(lg);
header_relativeLayout.setBackground(mDrawable);
```

searchbarColorID is the `ID` of the `Color` i defined in `values/color.xml`. This code above just works fine when executed over an `onClick-Event` of a button but not immediatly after Startup in `onResume`. Instead of Setting a Gradient he fills the Header completely with the ColorID `searchbar`. From a Log.e i know that he jumps to this code and i also know that the `ColorID` is the same which i saved in `sharedpreferences` before killing the app!

**Notice**
I went trough my whole code and i'm not Setting anywhere else the `Background-Color` of `Header_relativeLayout`.

So why does he execute the code above but not Setting a gradient Color? Instead he completely fills the Header_relativeLayout. I think i'm missing a small Detail..

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory.html

Comment: @pskink thank you, but at what should i set my Focus. I'm relatively new to Android.

Comment: just return your Shader in the factory method

Comment: @pskink can you provide a code-example which is adjusted to my code. This would make it more clear to me and you could earn some Reputation! Sounds like a win-win-Situation to me ! ;)

Comment: Im mobile right now so i cannot type much but call setShaderFactory on your ShapeDrawable thats it

Comment: i'm back, have you managed to to assemble the blocks of code?

Comment: @pskink i will try now that's why i'm on. you know it's chirstmas time. I will give you Feedback!

Comment: @pskink he wants me to pass a `ShaderFactory`. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: @pskink got it run and it works like a charm! Post it as an answere with a small Explanation and i will mark as accepted! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    final ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory shaderFactory = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
        @Override
        public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
            Log.d(TAG, "resize >>> " + width + " x " + height + " <<<");
            return new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        }
    };
    mDrawable.setShaderFactory(shaderFactory);
    View v = new View(this);
    v.setBackground(mDrawable);
    setContentView(v);
```

notice that `resize` method will be called when `View v` gets its final size so it will work even if called in `onCreate` method